# Laravel 6.* Blade: Button Onclick Event not Invoking Javascript at the bottom of the page

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a form with two hidden input fields to hold the longitude and latitude of the current user who is trying to submit the form, i now wrote javascript below the blade file to set obtain the current gps location and set it to the two fields so it can be submitted together with the form but the Method is never being invoked. Please what is the possible problem, I'm using Laravel 6.*

```
<script type="application/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="application/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var y = document.getElementById("lat");
        var z = document.getElementById("lng");


        function getLocation() {
            if ("geolocation" in broswer) {
                alert(navigator.geolocation)
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition, showError);
            } else {
                alert("System");
            }
        }


        function showPosition(position) {
            y.innerHtml.value = position.coords.latitude;
            z.innerHtml.value = position.coords.longitude;
        }

        function showError(error) {
            switch (error.code) {
                case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
                    alert("Permission Denied")
                    break;
                case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
                    alert("Position not available")
                    break;
                case error.TIMEOUT:
                    alert("Timed out")
                    break;
                case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
                    alert("Unknown Error")
                    break;
            }
        }
    })

</script>

<form class="form" method="PUT" action="{{ route('newBid') }}">
    @csrf
    <input type="number" class="form-control" name="amount" placeholder="0.00" required /><br/>
    <input type="hidden" name="auction_id" value="{{ $auction->id }}" />
    <button type="submit" onclick="getLocation()" class="btn btn-danger btn-block">
        {{ __('Bid') }}
    </button>
    <input type="hidden" id="lat" value="">
    <input type="hidden" id="lng" value="">
</form>
```

Comment: How is this related to Laravel or PHP after all? As there are multiple JS functions, which of these is not invoked? What have you tried to debug the problem?

Comment: If you know that it’s working with pure html, what have you tried to check for the differences? Please don’t be rude to people who try to help you

Answer (score 1):

Usually, when that happens, it's because the form is submitted before de onclick can be fired. Try changing the type of your `submit` to `button` and then, at the end of your `getLocation` function, call the `submit` function of your form

```
<script type="application/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>

    <script type="application/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var y = document.getElementById("lat");
            var z = document.getElementById("lng");


            function getLocation() {
                if ("geolocation" in broswer) {
                    alert(navigator.geolocation)
                    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition, showError);
                } else {
                    alert("System");
                }
                // we submit the form manually
                $('.form').submit();
            }        


            function showPosition(position) {
                y.innerHtml.value = position.coords.latitude;
                z.innerHtml.value = position.coords.longitude;
            }

            function showError(error) {
                switch (error.code) {
                    case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
                    alert("Permission Denied")   
                        break;
                    case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
                    alert("Position not available")   
                        break;
                    case error.TIMEOUT:
                    alert("Timed out")   
                        break;
                    case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
                    alert("Unknown Error")   
                        break;
                }
            }
        })

    </script>

<form class="form" method="PUT" action="{{ route('newBid') }}">@csrf
                                                <input type="number" class="form-control" name="amount" placeholder="0.00" required /><br/>
                                                <input type="hidden" name="auction_id" value="{{ $auction->id }}" />
                                                <!-- we changed the type to button -->
                                                <button type="button" onclick="getLocation()" class="btn btn-danger btn-block">
                                                    {{ __('Bid') }}


                                                </button>
                                                <input type="hidden"  id="lat" value="">
                                                <input type="hidden" id="lng" value="">
                                            </form>
```

Comment: I used laravel UI in generating my interface, with bootstrap and VUE ui which is new to laravel 6, could this be the reason? has anyone successfully called javascript in the page in laravel 6?